# Change Background Color of A Href Block On Finger Touch

Tags: android, jquery, button, colors, background

Here is my jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Wgajs/4/

I don't know how to achieve the same effect using jquery, when a user presses the button/link with their fingers. I've gone to the website but find it very confusing and don't know what to look for.

The reason I require jquery is because this effect does not work properly on Android mobile browsing. When you scroll down the page and touch a link, the highlighted green color gets all buggy and only shows partially, or worse, is split up and jaggedy.

So I am asking, could someone show me how to take the same effect of the "active" css class when the link turns green on click - and change it so it works when a user touches the button on a smartphone (using jquery)?

Answer (score 0):

try this solution

***CSS***

```
a.menuButton:active, activeBtn {... // Add activeBtn
```

***JS***

```
 $(function() {
   $('a.menuButton').on('mousedown', function(){
          $(this).addClass('activeBtn')        
        }
        )​​​​​​;
   $('a.menuButton').on('mouseup', function(){
          $(this).removeClass('activeBtn')        
        }
    );  

});
```

***[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abaksheyev/Wgajs/5/)***

​

Comment: Thankyou for the response. Unfortunately, the issue is still present. Would you like me to update a jsfiddle with the proper code?

Comment: see jsfddle, class is set with Jquery

Comment: You must be patient with me.. perhaps I am doing something wrong - but I copy/pasted exact and now I see nothing when pressing the link from my phone - it is always gray.

Comment: This is my code: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $stylesheet; ?>" type="text/css">
<script>
$(window).load(function() {
//Code
$(function() {
   $('a.menuButton').on('mousedown', function(){
          $(this).addClass('menuButtonActive ')        
        }
        );
   $('a.menuButton').on('mouseup', function(){
          $(this).removeClass('menuButtonActive ')        
        }
    );  

});
//End Code
 });
</script>